# null values in jasper report with xml remote datasource when report query returns empty set

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a report with `title` section like this

"Exempt report by " + $F{dt}

I define dt field as follows:

```
<field name="dt" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ancestor::data/@dt]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

my `xpath2` query is

```
/data/row
```

I use xml remote datasource, here is input (this is from remote service, I cannot change)

```
<data dt="03.10.2014">
    <!-- some data like <row id="42" label="text" />, but now it is empty -->
</data>
```

I want 'When No Data' All Sections, No Detail

But when are there no `row` nodes in xml, I get this in title

```
Exempt report by null
```

But `dt` still exists in xml, I want `Exempt report by 03.10.2014`

How should I define `dt` field? Should I change report query?

I interact with jasper server via REST api and only pass jrxml and xml url, so I can change only report template (jrxml)

Comment: IMHO field $F{dt} placed in title band is incorrect way. You haven't records, so you haven't values of fields. Try to use variable $V{dt} instead of field

Comment: yes, but then how can I fill `$V{dt}` from xml?

Comment: I am can't find solution with using variable

Answer (score 0):

Change report query from `data/row` to `/data`. 
In this case report will contain record, therefore @dt will have not null value. 
 But this solution reqires that $F{dt} must be placed into Detail band. 
In test report I consider that node `<data>` have only one (or zero) node `<row>`.

test xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>   
    <data dt="03.10.2014">
        <row id="42" label="text42"/>
    </data> 
</root>
```

report (maked in iReport 4.8.0)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="emptyXML" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="66c63e65-62f4-4fd9-aa1a-78c5c7d72620">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/root/data]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="dt" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@dt]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[row/@id]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="label" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[row/@label]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="e9831b27-7468-4117-803b-11026ee72942" x="57" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dt}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="dd52ac3a-9d1a-427b-8cb8-c5e50c0afec0" x="57" y="20" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="3d1e10ec-4e7a-472c-9d87-8170cf21681b" x="174" y="20" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

If exist xml with many `<row>` then this report must be changed. Probably insert subreport into detail band and move `$F{id)` and `$F{text}` into subreport.